# Hive UDF class getting Instantiated for each call of function

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hive-udf

I have created One Hive UDF class and register its function in spark.
In hive query inside spark session object  i call this function.
Now when i run my code i observe on each time when function called it
create new instance of UDF class.

Is it normal behavior on each call should it create new instance?

Is it version specific issue?